# MSBuild WriteLinesToFile without new line at the end

Tags: msbuild

I want to write a number in a text file using WriteLinesToFile but the task is putting a line feed at the end which causes me trouble when i want to read or combine in other places

Example:

```
<WriteLinesToFile File="$(TextFile)" Lines="@(BuildNumber)" Overwrite="true"/>
```

**UPDATE as the user comment below**:

The problem that I had was that I was using a very simple command in `Property` to read the content of a file `$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(TextFile)"))` and I really want to use this one but it also included the line feed from `WriteLinesToFiles`. I ended up using similar solution like yours using `ReadLinesFromFile`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a slight dissconnect between the title and the description. I would have liked to post this "answer" as an edit, but do not have [enough reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) :) 
Do you have a problem with the newline at the end of a file, or do you have a problem ignoring that newline? Could you please clarify?

One way how I suppose you could ignore that newline follows.

This small snippet of code writes a build number to a file, then reads it out and then increments the number read by 1.

```
<Target Name="Messing_around">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <StartBuildNumber>1</StartBuildNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <AlsoStartBuildNumber Include="1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Use a property 
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(ProjectDir)test.txt" Lines="$(StartBuildNumber)" Overwrite="true"/>      
  -->
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(ProjectDir)test.txt" Lines="@(AlsoStartBuildNumber)" Overwrite="true"/>
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(ProjectDir)test.txt">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Lines"
          ItemName="BuildNumberInFile"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OldBuildNumber>@(BuildNumberInFile)</OldBuildNumber>
    <NewBuildNumber>$([MSBuild]::Add($(OldBuildNumber), 1))</NewBuildNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Stored build number: @(BuildNumberInFile)"/>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="New build number: $(NewBuildNumber)"/>
</Target>
```

And this is what I see

```
Output:
1>Build started xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx.
1>Messing_around:
1>  Stored build number: 1
1>  New build number: 2
1>
1>Build succeeded.
```

If you attempting to read, in an MSBuild Task, a single line containing only a number from a file with a trailing line feed, then you should not have a problem.

As a side note: With the little information at hand I'd assume that `BuildNumber` is an `Item` in an `ItemGroup`. If you have only one build number to deal with, perhaps `Property` may have been an option. But then, again, I haven't been tinkering with MSBuild for too long. So, I am open to feedback on the `Item` vs `Property` issue.

Comment: I apologize for not being very clear with my problem and not posting my complete problem but it was to late i couldn't edit it anymore. However, the problem that i had was that i was using a very simple command in `Property` to read the content of a file `$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(TextFile)"))` and i really want to use this one but it also included the line feed from WriteLinesToFiles. I ended up using similar solution like yours using ReadLinesFromFile.